# I moved part of code to the class. Now I get runtime error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I had a working C# 2010 WEB app.
I moved part of code to a new class as follows:

```
namespace ShowDiagram1
{
    public class MyDraw : WebForm1
    {
        public void DrawPicture () {
            ...
            bitmap.Save(Server.MapPath("pic1.jpg"), ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            Image1.ImageUrl = this.ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");
             ...
        }
    }
}
```

The error message is as follows:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 85: Image1.ImageUrl = ResolveUrl("pic1.jpg");

pic1.jpg is created okay in previous line.

Image1 is the element on WebForm1

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you aren't initializing Image1 before trying to set its ImageUrl. What goes in the "..." before `bitmap.Save(...`?

Answer (score 1):

The Image1 variable isn't being initialized. If this is code that was copied from a webforms, you'll probably find the initialization code in the ".designer" file of the original webforms. Just search the solution for that variable, and you'll find the necessary code.

Comment: I found the following code in WebForm1 designer: protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image Image1;